# IPA file does not show all code like that of build

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build, ipa

I am creating an IPA file of my application that holds permission to access the apple health kit data. I am getting a screen presented in front of me for allowing the user to allow or reject the permission when I build the app in my iPhone directly. But after creating an IPA file, I am not getting the screen asking permission for getting apple health data on all physical devices. Can anyone suggest to me why am I getting such sort of error?
[I have added the privacy policy permission for health kit in .plist too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARoBR.png)

Comment: Your question is a wild goose chose since you aren't giving out much information.

Comment: So You mean that IPA file is not working properly.

Comment: Yes, Apple health kit permission pop up does not appear in IPA  but it works fine in the build version of the app

Comment: Have you also added `HealthKit` from Capabilities?

Comment: Got it fixed Thanks @JohnG. Healthkit permission was missing for the release version.